# ¿Como lanzar un script desde un boton otro script?

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica

Soy nuevo en `python` y estoy intentado construir un UI en maya 2022, quiero lanzar un script desde un botón de mi UI, estoy utilizando `import sys` y añadiendo el path pero no me lo encuentra.

```
import sys

sys.path.append("C:\00_Pose")
```

En el archivo Maya.env he puesto el path correspondiente pero sigue sin encontrarlo

```
PYTHONPATH = C:\00_Pose
```

Después creo una función y esa función la llamo desde el botón con command

```
def pick():
    cmds.file("C:/00_Pose/Picker.py")
```

Pero no encuentra el path

```
Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 30: File not found: "C:/00_Pose/Picker.py"
```

Sin embargo si busco los directorios a los que tiene acceso encuentra el directorio

```
import sys

pathList = sys.path

for path in pathList:

    print(path)

C:

C:\00_Pose

C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2022\plug-ins\ATF\scripts
```

He intentado otras formas que he visto por ahí como `subprocess`, con exec pero no he sido capaz de hacerlas funcionar por lo que no se si es un error de código o es algo de los accesos a los directorios en windows 10, estoy bastante perdido :(

Gracias.

Comment: No tengo experiencia con Maya, pero solo un comentario, especificar una ruta con la cadena  `"C:\00_Pose"` me pone nervioso :) Esa `\\` sin escapar tiene mucho peligro, mas aun si va seguida de un cero, esa es la secuencia de escape para el carácter nulo y eso en sys.path es suficiente para hacer que importlib explosione...

Comment: Gracias, no lo sabia, aunque lo he cambiado sigo sin poder acceder al script, seguiré investigando  :)